# Is it okay to use objects which implement Parcelable in Presenters?

Tags: android, android-mvp, android-moxy

Is it okay to use objects which implement `Parcelable` in Presenters?

If i have some object in presenter that implements `Parcelable` does it means that my presenter depends on android sdk object(`Parcelable`)?

Comment: I think we need to see a little more code for context.